# Iptables - source or destination check first?

Tags: iptables, port

So I'm running a server with iptables config and I've only been checking for destinations. Here is what the config structure is. Top of config has a list of ip addresses to drop followed by rate-limiting on specific destination ports then accepting the one's rate limited. In the end I blocked all the ports. So the one's not accepted are blocked.

Now I need to fix a source port match somewhere in the config. I want to block udp source port X so where would this come?

I placed it at the end of the config but I am not sure if it works. Would it check the destination of that source port first and allow it? or would it just block the source port.

**UPDATE:**

Here is what it sort of looks like.

```
# Block Source Port 53 - The commands below slow the SSH down
#-A INPUT -p udp --sport 53 -j DROP
#-A INPUT -p tcp --sport 53 -j DROP 

#
# Destinations
#

# Accept PPTPD VPN Ports 
// Commands go here

# Accept IP Rules and Port Range
// Commands go here

# Rate-Limit ICMP Ping Requests
// Commands go here - Used with the iptables recent module

# Rate-Limit Game Servers Ports
// Commands go here - Used with the iptables recent module

# Accept the Ports Rate-Limited above
// Commands go here

# Drop All Other TCP & UDP Ports
-A INPUT -p tcp -j DROP
-A INPUT -p udp -j DROP
-A INPUT -j DROP
```

I tried the source port 53 block at the end of the config where it didn't seem to work possibly because the destination match of that source came first. Now I put it on top of the config or even in the middle somewhere and it seems to work but my SSH/SFTP login seems awfully delayed, such that it even times-out sometimes after I enter the username although my own IP is accepted among the IP addresses accepted. I also just tried blocking source port 53 at UDP because that's what I actually need but it would still cause that delay. Not sure what UDP has to do with ssh/sftp. Maybe the delay is caused by the source port checking actually?

Comment: Paste you iptables config ... it will be easier

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5845839/ here is what it sort of looks like. I tried the source port 53 block at the end of the config where it didn't seem to work possibly because the destination match of that source came first. Now I put it on top of the config and it seems to work but my SSH login seems delayed after I enter the username although my own IP is accepted among the IP addresses accepted.

Comment: Actually not just the SSH, it has slowed everything down. Even SFTP. I have also tried adding it after accepting specific IPs but it still causes the delays.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, and without looking deeply, you're blocking DNS responses.  That will **most definitely** slow all things ssh-related down, and probably a lot of other stuff, too.

Comment: Oh yes I just looked at that. It's port 53. I'm getting attacked by this port at UDP protocol and my server makes outgoing responses through icmp. What should I do? About 200 ips attack so rate limit is not an option for me as that is per ip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was blocking source port 53 which were DNS responses that was causing the issue. Undoing that, fixed it.